# MongoDB SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get issuer certificate

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I have enabled SSL on `MongoDB` with optional SSL connection: `preferred`.

I have used `lets encrypt` in order to obtain SSL certificates. SSLs works as expected and in `mongod.log` file I can see that:

```
2018-06-02T06:46:26.664+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from MY_SERVER_IP:45442 #2953818 (121 connections now open)
2018-06-02T06:46:26.664+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2953818] SSL mode is set to 'preferred' and connection 2953818 to MY_SERVER_IP:45442 is not using SSL.
```

Now on the same host I try to connect to mongo using mongo client command like below:

```
mongo --ssl --host mongo.example.com --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongo.pem --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/ca.pem
```

when I use `SSL` mongo gives error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://mongo.example.com:27017/
2018-06-02T06:48:34.156+0000 E NETWORK  [thread1] SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get issuer certificate
2018-06-02T06:48:34.164+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get issuer certificate :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Why it reports that `unable to get issuer certificate`? Is there something in between that I have missed? Could someone shed some light on this?

---

**EDIT1:**

I tried the below command too and got the error `network error`:

```
root@example2:~# mongo --ssl --host='mongo.domain.com' --port=27017
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11
connecting to: mongo.domain.com:27017/test
2018-06-02T08:31:13.501+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host 'mongo.domain.com:27017'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:231:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Now getting error `network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host`.

In MongoDB server log it reports that:

```
Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSLHandshakeFailed. Ending connection from 127.0.0.1:32793 (connection id: 358957)
```

Answer (score 5):

By removing `CAFile: /etc/ssl/ca.pem` option from `mongoDB` config file, problem gone away.

Comment: It does go away, and that helped, but then mongod warns of no SSL certificate validation because no CA file.

Comment: @jma I have used `x509 self signed certificate` using `openssl` and provided both `CAFile` & `PEMKeyFile` to mongodb. With this configuration I have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use tls arguments instead of ssl, in the following way:

```
mongo "mongodb://MONGOHOST:27017"  \
        --tlsCertificateKeyFile /etc/certs/mongodb-cert-key.pem \
        --tls \
        --tlsCAFile /etc/certs/CA-cert.pem
```

where

- MONGOHOST should be in your /etc/hosts file
- mongodb-cert-key.pem should have the certificate AND the key
- CA-cert.pem must contain the certificate of the CA related to the previous certificate (mongodb-cert-key.pem)

https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/configuration-options/#security-options